# Regex that matches word in file only if its at the end of the line

Tags: regex, sublimetext, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

So if I have something in a file like: `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"`

is there a regex out there that matches `html` only if it is at the end of that line. So I just want it to grab that `html` from the `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"` at the end of the line and nowhere else if its not at the end of a line. So if theres something like `html DocumentRoot` it shouldn't match because its not at the end.

I have tried doing some regexs like: `^.*html$`
and `^DocumentRoot\s.*"/.*/.*/.*html"$`
just experimenting but I couldn't figure out one that grabs html only at the end of a line.

So is there a regex out there that grabs html only at the end of a line?

Comment: What about just `html$`?

Comment: To add to what @WiktorStribiżew is saying, keep in mind that you don't always need to match a full line. You can match partial lines as well, as is the case with his suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, one more question though if I want to match html at the end of a specific line like `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"` and only a specific line and no where else in the file is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is the specific bit about the line?

Comment: This link might help you. https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/regex-match-a-particular-line/22692/4

Comment: `html` would be the specific bit so only matching that `html` within `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"` and nowhere else in the file. Because if I use just `html$` it will match any instance of html at the end of the line. So I was just wondering is there a way only to match it to the Document root path?

Comment: So, `DocumentRoot` must be at the start? What are you doing with this line, replacing? What should be the final result?

Comment: yes `DocumentRoot` must be at the start and yeah replacing it with a different word basically.

Comment: Then you do not even need any lookarounds. `^(DocumentRoot\h.*/)html"$` -> `$1<NEW VALUE>"`

Comment: That worked! Thank you, I appreciate it

Comment: @B.Gordan See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755084/3832970). I wanted more details to show you easier way to solve the task. Not all regex flavors have lookbehinds, lookaheads or `\K`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for the info

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=^DocumentRoot "/var/www/)html(?="$)`

Use a positive lookbehind `(?<=...)` to find a line that starts `^` with `DocumentRoot "/var/www/` and then a positive lookahead `(?=...)` to ensure the line ends with `"$`

Answer (score 0):

`^` is an anchor for the **beginning**

`$` is an anchor for the **end**

You have the answer yourself, you just don't need to use both of them at once.

Use only `html"$`, as suggested by @Wiktor.

And if you also want lines that include anything else, use:
`(prefix).*html"$`

Comment: OP only wants to match `html` at the end of a specific line, please fix or remove the answer.

Comment: "is there a regex out there that matches html only if it is at the end of that line" what...?

Comment: It is not what OP wants, see [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754817/regex-that-matches-word-in-file-only-if-its-at-the-end-of-the-line#comment90469542_51754817).

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(DocumentRoot\h.*/)html(")$
```

and replace with `$1<NEW_VALUE>$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bin4Ln/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(DocumentRoot\h.*/)` - Group 1: `DocumentRoot` literal substring, a horizontal whitespace, any 0+ chars other than line break and then `/`
- `html` - a literal substring
- `(")` - Group 2: a `"` char
- `$` - end of line.

To only match that `html`, you may also use

```
^DocumentRoot\h.*/\Khtml(?="$)
```

Then, you'd only need to replace with `<NEW_VALUE>`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bin4Ln/2).

Here, instead of capturing groups, `\K` match reset operator is used to "clear" the matched text before `html` and a positive lookahead chech is implemented to only allow a match that is followed with `"` at the end of the line.